# Android OS Upgrade Notification/Receiver?

Tags: android, operating-system

Is it possible to get any Notification/Receiver if the OS has been upgraded in android?
Means is there any Receiver or API to get the change in OS.?

Answer (score 0):

You can keep the version in the shared Preferences and Check the storage version with the latest version by using 
{
int currentVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
or
android.os.Build.VERSION.RELEASE
}

and can generate notification inside it

Comment: Is there any REceiver for this ? if i store it in the sharedpref then need to check it every time. so Receiver or notification will be best for this.